Generating walmart canada WM_SEC.AUTH_SIGNATURE and getting orders
I'm trying to requests orders from walmart canada API, but I'm not being able to do so. I'm generating the WM_SEC.AUTH_SIGNATURE and the timestamp through the JAR file that they provide in their documentation, but when I try to request using that signature I am receiving this error code:
{"error":[{"code":"UNAUTHORIZED.GMP_GATEWAY_API","field":"UNAUTHORIZED","description":"Unauthorized","info":"Unauthorized token or incorrect authorization header. Please verify correct format: \"Authorization: Basic Base64Encode(clientId:clientSecret)\" For more information, see https://developer.walmart.com/#/apicenter/marketPlace/latest#apiAuthentication.","severity":"ERROR","category":"DATA","causes":[],"errorIdentifiers":{}}]}

I tried generating the signature with self generated code but I was not able to do it correctly.
Can someone help me to request orders? The endpoint I am trying to get is this one: https://marketplace.walmartapis.com/v3/ca/orders
